# Nokogiri: parse, extract and return <tr> content in HTML table

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to parse a HTML table. It is basically the sixth `<tr>` tag in the HTML:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>date</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="white">
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
    <td align=right colspan=2 id=ptitle name=ptitle>
        <font size=3>this is my title</font><br>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height=10 align=left colspan=2 valign=top>
        <table border=0 width="100%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" align=right><font size=2>this is my subtitle</font></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
    <td valign=top>
        <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
this is a line
</tr>
<tr>
this is a line</tr>
<tr>
this is a line</tr>
<tr>
this is a line</tr>
<tr>
this is a line</tr>
<tr>
this is a line</tr>
<tr>
this is a line</tr>
<tr>
this is a line</tr>
<tr>
this is a line</tr>

    </table>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

My Ruby code looks like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
url = <website-name>
data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
data.at('<tr>').next[6].text
```

But it wont work. How do I use Nokogiri to extract all these `<tr>this is a line</tr>` code?

Ideally I'd like it to be in one variable and including the HTML as I would like to but it into another website.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. That's not Sinatra code, it's Ruby code. And, the Sinatra tag isn't needed since your code in your question doesn't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
rows = data.css("td[valign='top'] table tr") # All the <tr>this is a line</tr>
rows.each do |row|
  puts row.text # Will print all the 'this is a line'
end
```

Comment: This works! Great! Thanks a lot!
Now I would like to get the whole html code instead of only the content (which I suppose is a feature of the nokogiri). Any chance to get the html for each row?
Thank you so much!

Comment: on the `rows` variable you have all the `html` of each `<tr>`. Just keep using the `.css('...')` method on each row to scrap their html.

Comment: great. Seems to work, now I am trying to get it in my html site:
get '/' do
url = <url name>
data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
@rows = data.css("td[valign=top] table tr") 

erb :muster
end


in the muster-view there is the following code:

HTML-Stuff
<% @rows[2] %>
<% @rows[3] %>
<% @rows[4] %>
<% @rows[5] %>


as I only want the second till fifth row.
Sinatra returns an internal server error on localhost :((

Comment: Hi Alfonso, I had UTF-8 problems in my html (it was late last night ;)), now the code runs but does not put the [at]rows content. The code is <% [at ]rows[2] %> .I tried <% puts [at]rows[2] %> and <% [at]rows[2].text %> Dont see any html code that is parsed into [at]rows :(

Comment: while [at]rows means the actual variable (see above). but stackoverflow says that i could only name only one addtional user :)

Comment: You are missing the `=` when using the tag `<% %>`. To print text you must use `<%= @rows[2] %>`. The `=` tells rails that you want to print on screen the content inside the `<% %>` tag.