# How parse a table and extract data for last 6 months Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Im getting confused at this task. I have a table from a demo bank site(check the screen below).
Need to extract data only from only last 6 months.
[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iafN5.png)
I have tried severeal anwsers from these topics:
[Parse table using Nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850862/parse-table-using-nokogiri)
[Nokogiri: parse, extract and return <tr> content in HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054950/nokogiri-parse-extract-and-return-tr-content-in-html-table)

But im still confused how to extract data only from last 6 months without to extract all data and after to check date.

Is any possbile options to extract data in right way ?

The table class Im using to find table in nokogiri is class="tblInf rowOver".

[Table](https://www.sberbank.ru/common/img/uploaded/secure/demosbol/general.html#/history_operations)

Code I use:

```
def get_transactions
  cells = ''
  $b.a(:href => "#/history_operations").click!
  sleep(5)
  $p = Nokogiri::HTML.parse($b.html)
  table = $p.css('#simpleTable0')
  table.search('tr').each do |tr|
    payment_description = tr.search('.paymentDescription').text
    p = payment_description.split('  ',-1)
    for i in p
      puts i.delete('  ')
      end


    # puts cells
  end
```

Comment: Please include minimal examples of both input and desired output. Please include these directly in the question, instead of linking to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's helpful if you can post some example HTML rather than a screenshot of the page. Particularly as this task is about parsing HTML.

Why do you need to check the date beforehand? Nokogiri is pretty fast, and I can't imagine the table is so big that checking as you parse will be useful. Having reviewed the Nokogiri docs, I can't see any way to do what you're describing. You'll need to grab the data from the table, and then reject any rows that have a date older than six months.

Comment: I added link to table I need to parse. And I get that I can take away one table row and check date , but im still stuck at how to parse the table in right way bcs im getting https://imgur.com/a/mfvWGrE data with a lot of whitespaces. I tried to deleteit with .split but this ddidnt help. I also try .delete(' ') , but I dont need to delete all teh spaces. Im really stuck at this point.

Comment: This answer describes how to remove whitespace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634750/ruby-function-to-remove-all-white-spaces

You probably want .strip